# mapping over HList inside a function

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-level-computation, hlist

The following code seems obvious enough to compile and run

```
case class Pair(a: String, b: Int)

val pairGen = Generic[Pair]

object size extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseInt = at[Int](x => 1)
  implicit def caseString = at[String](_.length)
}

def funrun(p: Pair) = { 
  val hp: HList = pairGen.to(p)
  hp.map(size)
}
```

but the compiler says "could not find implicit value for parameter mapper". In my use case, I want to map over an HList to get and HList of String(s) and then convert the HList of String(s) into Scala List[String]. Any ideas?

Comment: If you remove the type of the hp, then the code will work as it is. So, instead of "val hp: HList = pairGen.to(p)" you should have "val hp = pairGen.to(p)"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First we can create a `Poly1` similar to `size` which we can use to map an `HList` to an `HList` of `Strings`.

```
object strings extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseInt = at[Int](_.toString)
  implicit def caseString = at[String](identity)
}
```

You were already using `Generic[Pair]` to turn a `Pair` into an `HList`, but you couldn't map over your `hp` because there is no evidence in your `funrun` that you can map over it. We can solve this by using implicit parameters.

```
def funRun[L <: HList, M <: HList](
  p: Pair
)(implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[Pair, L],
  mapper: Mapper.Aux[strings.type, L, M]
) = gen.to(p).map(strings)
```

- Our first implicit parameter `gen` can turn a `Pair` into an `HList`
  of type `L`.
- Our second implicit parameter `mapper` can use our `strings` polymorphic function to map an `HList` of type `L` to an `HList` of type `M`.

We can now use `funRun` to turn a `Pair` into an `HList` of `Strings` :

```
scala> funRun(Pair("abc", 12))
res1: shapeless.::[String,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]] = abc :: 12 :: HNil
```

But you wanted to return a `List[String]`. To turn our `HList` `M` (the result of mapping to `String`) to a `List[String]` we need a `ToTraversable`, so we add a third implicit parameter :

```
import shapeless._, ops.hlist._

def pairToStrings[L <: HList, M <: HList](
  p: Pair
)(implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[Pair, L],
  mapper: Mapper.Aux[strings.type, L, M],
  trav: ToTraversable.Aux[M,List,String]
): List[String] = gen.to(p).map(strings).toList
```

Which we can use as :

```
scala> pairToStrings(Pair("abc", 12))
res2: List[String] = List(abc, 12)
```

Comment: Thank you @Peter! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: After I closed this thread I've been going in circles trying to understand why the following basic enhancement to composite type does not work: `  class A[T](val x: T);

  object g extends Poly1 {
    implicit def caseString = at[String] { identity }
  };

  def toStr[L <: HList](
      a: A[String]
  )(implicit 
      gen: Generic.Aux[A[String], L],
      mapper: Mapper[g.type, L]
  ) = gen.to(a).map(g)`

Comment: I'm getting `could not find implicit value for parameter mapper: shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper[g.type,gen.Repr]`.

Comment: Have you imported `shapeless.ops.hlist._` ?

Comment: Importing `shapeless.ops.hlist._` makes the above code work. Thank you @Peter! My use case has one additional twist - a variable parameter list. This code compiles REPL: ` case class A[T](a: T) 
  case class As(as: A[String]*)

  object f extends Poly1 {
    implicit def caseA = at[A[String]](identity)
  }
    
  def toStr[L <: HList, M <: HList](
        as: As
  )(implicit
        gen: Generic.Aux[As, L],
        mapper: Mapper.Aux[f.type, L, M]
  ) = gen.to(as).map(f)
   
  val a = A[String]("one")
  val as: As = As(a, a, a)`. BUT the call to `toStr(as)` gives the mapper error as before.

Comment: @arapmv If you experiment in the REPL, you will see that the output type (`gen.Repr`) from `Generic[As]` is `Seq[A[String]] :: HNil`. Your `g` function only has a case for `A[String]` so the `g` function cannot be used to map over an `HList` of type `gen.Repr`.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @Peter! Adding a case `implicit def caseGenAs = at[Seq[A[String]]](_.map({case A(a) => a}).mkString(","))` into `g` solves the problem.