# How to apply a separate function to each index of a known Shapelss HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

I know the type of an HList and I would like to apply a specific function to each of the specific items in the HList.  For example.

I know the type of the HList, in this case String :: Int :: String :: HNil

```
val values = "Hello World" :: 5 :: "Goodbye World" :: HNil
```

So I create a function from type => Int for each item.

```
val funcs =
  ((_: String) => 1) ::
  ((_: Int) => 2) ::
  ((_: String) => 3) ::
   HNil
```

I want to apply function 1 to value 1, function 2 to value 2, etc for each item in the list.  This is the best guess at what the function signature might look.  V

```
// V are the Values of type String :: Int :: String :: HNil
// F are the Functions of type (String => Int) :: (Int => Int) :: (String => Int) :: HNil
// R is the Int Results of type Int :: Int :: Int :: HNil
def applyFunction[V <: HList, F <: HList, R <: HList](v: V, f: F)(
   implicit ev: V =:= F,
   utcc: UnaryTCConstraint[F, Function[*, Int]]
): R
```

Now I'm struggling with how to actually implement this function or if maybe Shapeless already has something that does this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard type class [`shapeless.ops.hlist.ZipApply`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L2274-L2301)

```
funcs.zipApply(values) // 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: HNil
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32454198/4993128) as an inspiration, I came up with the following:

```
import shapeless._

val values = "Hello World" :: 5 :: "Goodbye World" :: HNil

val funcs = ((_: String) => 1) ::
            ((_: Int) => 2) ::
            ((_: String) => 3) :: HNil

object applyTo extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseInt = at[(Int=>Int,Int)]      {case (f,v) => f(v)}
  implicit def caseStr = at[(String=>Int,String)]{case (f,v) => f(v)}
}

funcs.zip(values).map(applyTo)
//1 :: 2 :: 3 :: HNil: Int :: Int :: Int :: shapeless.HNil
```

Comment: It is unfortunate that I will have to add a poly case for each type though.  It would be nice to not have to add a case tot the applyTo if another data type is introduced.  There are a lot of data types in this world.  However, this is a great start.